# Remove trailing period in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a some email adresses in a sqlite database.  Some of them end with a period.  I ran a select query using REGEXP to target those emails.  How can I remove the trailing period.  Below is my select query showing me my emails ending in periods which it did find emails.

[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FWgQ.jpg)

```
select *
from links
where email REGEXP '\.$'
```

I tried using an update query with TRIM but could not get it work right

```
UPDATE links
SET email = trim('email','.');
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Result: UNIQUE constraint failed: links.email
At line 1:
UPDATE links
SET email = trim('email','.');
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes: `SET email = trim(email,'.')`

Answer (score 0):

If your email has several sentences each ending with period and

option 1 - you want to get rid of only the last period, you can use something like following. If there are spaces after last period, use rtrim() first.

```
select  substr(a.email, 0, length(email))
from (select 'This is some email. I want to delete the last period.' email)
a
```

option 2 - you want to get rid of all period occurrences, use replace() like following

```
select  replace(a.email, '.', '')
from (select 'This is some email. I want to delete the last period.' email)
a
```